# Get wrong context in android

Tags: android, android-context

I'm quite new to Android developing and I'm currently building a note-taking app with text note and checklist function. However, there is a bug that I'm currently confuse with. It happens when user try to add new item to the checklist and the app just route the method to an unwanted one.

I don't know what's wrong with my code, might be something with the context. Therefore I will put my source code here and hopefully someone might figure it out. Thanks for your support

Here is the relevent code after user clicking add item:

NoteEditorActivity

```
ChecklistManager.newInstance(NoteEditorActivity.this).create(item);
```

ChecklistManager

```
public long create(CheckItem item) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.CL_COL_ID, item.getId());
    //put some data
    Uri result = clContext.getContentResolver().insert(ChecklistContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values); //BUG: insert command points to notecontentprovider's one
    long id = Long.parseLong(result.getLastPathSegment());
    return id;
}
```

and it route to the insert method in NoteContentProvider instead of the one in ChecklistContentProvider

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int type = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Long id;
    switch (type){
        case NOTES:
            id = db.insert(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, null, values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI at notecontent: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH_NOTE + "/" + id);
}
```

Here is the bug

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI at notecontent: content://cmc.note.data.provider/checklist
                  at cmc.note.data.NoteContentProvider.insert(NoteContentProvider.java:88)
                  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java)
                  at cmc.note.data.ChecklistManager.create(ChecklistManager.java:43)
                  at cmc.note.activities.NoteEditorActivity$1.onClick(NoteEditorActivity.java:107)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:163)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you have `NoteContentProvider` registered for the authority you're querying on. The `UriMatcher` there doesn't have a match for the `checklist` path, so it's throwing that `IllegalArgumentException`.

Generally speaking, apps only need one Provider, which determines the result data from the path and ID on the URI. You can easily combine the two Provider classes you currently have into one, and merge their `UriMatcher` setups and CRUD methods. When a request is received, simply determine which table you need to access from the URI using the matcher, and perform the necessary database operation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat points out 'content://cmc.note.data.provider/checklist' is unknown uri. Check your URI_MATCHER, it doesn't have 'cmc.note.data.provider/checklist', or may be your switch is wrong (case NOTES)